# How to access a socket server connected to heroku

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

I've created a client script and a server script that work fine when the server is run on my computer, however I'd like to host the server on heroku, I've set up everything and got the heroku application to run however I'm having trouble connecting the client to that server

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5001))
s.listen(5)
```

client.py

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('applicationhere.herokuapp.com/0.0.0.0', 5001))
```

Doing that returns an error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I'm not really good with using sockets so I'm really confused on what the problem is.

Comment: `'applicationhere.herokuapp.com/0.0.0.0'` is not a valid hostname. if the hostname is `applicationhere.herokuapp.com`, try with `s.connect(('applicationhere.herokuapp.com', 5001))`

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the hostname cannot be resolved.
If you bind the server socket on all ip addresses with
`server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5001))`
then you should be able to connect to the server using the public ip/DNS 
`client_socket.connect(('applicationhere.herokuapp.com', 5001))` 
Obviously the client must know how to resolve `applicationhere.herokuapp.com` and there is nothing blocking the connection (E.g. firewalls).

Comment: I'm met with the following error: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: you can check a few things but depending on the client network it indeed looks like a networking problem. if a telnet or nc test fails then the socket connection won't work neither. `telnet applicationhere.herokuapp.com 5001` or `nc -zv applicationhere.herokuapp.com 5001`